# Coefficients for a multidimensional plane wave expansion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, klein-gordon-equation, plane-wave

If I have, for example, $\psi_{n_x,n_y,n_z}=e^{\frac{\pi i}{L}(n_xx+n_yy+n_zz)}$ and $E_{n_x,n_y,n_z}=mc^2\sqrt{1+\frac{\frac{\pi^2}{L^2}(n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2)}{m^2c^2}}$

and I want to find the wave function at a certain time in terms of an initial state $\psi(t=0,x,y,z)$

then is it the case that $\psi(t) = \sum_{n_x=1}^\infty\sum_{n_y=1}^\infty\sum_{n_z=1}^\infty c_{n_x,n_y,n_z}\psi_{n_x,n_y,n_z}e^{\frac{-iE_{n_x,n_y,n_z}t}{\hbar}}$

and that $c_{n_x,n_y,n_z}$ can be determined in terms of the inital state $\psi(t=0,x,y,z)$ as such:

$c_{n_x,n_y,n_z}=\int\int\int \psi_{n_x,n_y,n_z}^*\psi(t=0,x,y,z) dxdydz$

?

Comment: you seem to be missing relativistic with non-relativistic equations…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero How so?

Comment: you basically have $E=mc^2\times $[something] in the right…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes, it is relativistic quantum mechanics. What makes you think it is non-relativistic?

Comment: sorry… I realize there is a typos in a previous comment: missing-> mixing.

Comment: well you appear to be attempting a partial wave expansion in space only, whereas a relativistic treatment would treat time on par with the spatial coordinates.  I’m slightly confused by your question and I think some context would improve it but I suppose it’s technically correct…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Disregarding relativity, could you recommend some sources for finding the coefficients in the expansion, the $c_{n_x,n_y,n_z}$ ? I am really struggling with it.

Comment: Read *any* book on quantum mechanics or Hilbert spaces etc.

Comment: Also, don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: what you have is not really a plane wave expansion because of the $\psi_{n_x,n_y,n_z}$… what are you searching for?  An expansion of $\psi_{n_x,n_y,n_z}$ in plane waves?  A function of $t$ that is a solution to the SE is already in a plane-wave like form (in time) $\psi(t)=\sum_n \psi_n(x) e^{-i E_nt/\hbar}$…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I'm looking for a way to handle the coefficients in three dimensions

Comment: right but then there should not be any $\psi_{n_x,n_y,n_z}$, i.e. your expansion should.  be $\psi(x,y,z)=\sum c_{n_x}e^{i n_x x/L} \sum c_{n_z} e^{i n_z z/L} \sum c_{n_y} e^{i n_y y/L} $.  The expansion factorizes into independent $x,y,z$ expansions and each $c_{n_k}$ is obtained as in the 1d case.

Comment: See : https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_representation                                  and evolution operator                      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_evolution#:~:text=In%20quantum%20mechanics%2C%20the%20propagators,given%20by%20the%20scattering%20matrix.